# Использование одного из типов для TypeScript. React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Есть компонент PrimitiveTypeEditor, в который передаётся value типа EditorValue. Из него это value передаётся в компоненты TextBox, NumberInput и CheckBox.

В TextBox должен передаваться string, в NumberInput – number, в CheckBox – boolean.

В PropTypes есть метод oneOfType, а как реализовывать без него в TypeScript?

Вопрос — как реализовать интерфейс EditorValue, чтобы value могло быть нужным типом для компонентов

Ошибка:
[image: Ошибка в CheckBox.tsx]

Тип EditorValue

```
export type EditorValue = string | number | boolean;
```

Файл PrimitiveTypeEditor.tsx

```
class PrimitiveTypeEditor extends DojoReactComponent {
   render(): ReactElement {
      const { dataType, title, value }: PrimitiveTypeEditorState = this.state;

      /** Слушатель изменения значения редактора */
      const onChangeHandler = (newValue: EditorValue) => {
         this.setState({ value: newValue });
      };

      return (
         <div>
            {(() => {
               switch (dataType) {
                  case 'STRING':
                  case 'GUID':
                     return <TextBox
                        {...this.state}
                        title={title}
                        onChange={onChangeHandler} value={value}/>;
                  case 'INTEGER':
                  case 'DOUBLE':
                     return <NumberInput
                        {...this.state}
                        title={title}
                        onChange={onChangeHandler} value={value} type={dataType}/>;
                  case 'BOOLEAN':
                     return <CheckBox
                        {...this.state}
                        title={title}
                        onChange={onChangeHandler} value={value}/>;
                  case 'DATE':
                     return <DatePicker
                        {...this.state}
                        title={title}
                        onChange={onChangeHandler} value={value}/>;
                  default:
                     throw new Error('Использован несуществующий тип данных для PrimitiveTypeEditor');
               }
            })()}
         </div>
      );
   }
}

interface PrimitiveTypeEditorState {
   dataType?: EditorType,
   title?: string,
   value?: EditorValue
}
```

Файл CheckBox.tsx

```
const CheckBox: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ title, onChange, ...props }: Props) => {
   const [{ value = false, disabled = false, showLabel = true }, setProps] = useState(props);

   /** Callback-функция изменения значения */
   const onChangeHandler = (_:SyntheticEvent<HTMLElement>, { checked: newValue }: CheckboxProps) => onChange(newValue);

   /** Слушатели изменения необязательных свойств */
   useEffect(() => setProps(props),
      [props.value, props.disabled, props.showLabel]);

   return (
      <div className={'checkbox-input'}>
         <Checkbox
            onChange={onChangeHandler} checked={value}
            disabled={disabled}/>
         {showLabel && <div className={'input-title'}>{title}</div>}
      </div>
   );
};

interface Props {
   title: string,
   onChange: (value: EditorValue) => void,
   value?: EditorValue,
   placeholder?: string,
   disabled?: boolean,
   showLabel?: boolean,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть набросок решения на голом TypeScript. Увязал тип и значение в одной структуре, что позволяет их анализировать в паре ([Discriminating Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)). Благодаря этому число приходит туда где ожидается число, а boolean туда где ожидается boolean.

[Ссылка на песочницу](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEjwQR+EEDhBEEQQGEELwg1CsIKQQiDUoPhBBMIAWACgiBLAOwBcBTAJwDMBDAYytABEGKGBlCm8gOagA3kVDjQFAJ4AHKgC5QAcm4AVAEoBJAHIBxJQG4xEgG4MANgFcFoAM59BRwgF8ipSrUYt2nBroCqmmwixuLScopKAUGGoaBmVjb2-GQCTq7EhOTU9MysHFyaHgK0IYQSkrI2SjqqAKK6deqx5aYW1opklgC2AEa06W5ZHrneBQxsAPaWveasoq1hVZFsAPL+AEIAMnUtFQkdoF19A0QZ7jle+b4bk5NzDGRlFeHVG6urOwCC2nttiYpencHmRBplsp48j4uAV5nFXisvvU-uIDkkHKkwURXtCGKoqqAALy43gpIQAH1x0WClPGRWoJRooFpvimMzmzNxt3uVEenPGsKcQxAoEAWCDYQA8IDhEChEOhANIgQwho1YAGFJt0ZJMyFRKAAeVQAPme-0OqicFW1qoAFo8SooABRoxSqACURONJkmJAAJkLFpISBQ5gB+RTJRxnIZ0SxkJgUEja0A0XU+2iqKgADwot0zDuE8XarGcinVmu1uooeojqUNrvDGKECwqKYolhoTwABhns7nFAASYRo5ydrGEGNxhNJlNkNM0bQ9fo0IoySwUfOFxKgEugMtanX645LusNskm8St9tdhcnZdkVcUAdDosAOgok1JggdrpHY4n8cTJ4ZznG0qCYABrXMNzRbdSw1fdKz1IEeUeE87Ebc9kyoNsO1ATtQIgvtQEHNE3w-Rtv1-KNMn-KcgNTWhYQABRICDaGgotYN3eCK31GsBDQ-jMMvXDO2Y1jwNoJ9h1HajhTAQACEBQQAWEHgQAuEHQbBAAEQJURiuUAmP4bogxIEwqHxOQ6h9INJhoXhODhRYE2DKgw3QskLVRIs3PGCyqDHJhzAYWxbAMoyTLMvyrJsplmwkewHMUQySGMhNIqqaL3zsrhqH9ComG1ZJLHjWyHQS6gkvCtLzIy6ysvs6h3TiiowmtEhbBfcrWGJLrPPEc4A1sbCGqoMqcpsJiGBoBMLD1ZLUtMmrLLq2yRrQr1fUwl42o6rqiREUAXyOigds68aABpDqOvbnD67chhbBiaG-U9BC2iQCrIewDucuZLpgnd5oipaqEy1bxv2k72rOhy8pa8RPu+q1bVSbrQANUAs2oWdQt8qpDQdHUAHcADUixdABtJQ0SUABdet4m9H0PXe+God24bxvzOJ4fhkVACIQQBhEHQUBsEgeBYEQbBLtwUBAEYQQXlMFwBJEBQCVQAlbBADYQFARa0+BAHYQQApEBQQBREHgdBABkQWBAHkQDAXzUl9KjkUBoE3awed5ioRTllAtOF23XYN0B9YNxB5VN13YE0wBxEGQNS8CdwBEEHlQBuEGweX5VAU3tOwQAJEAz5TsDl+BcGgK3Pa98QRUgLS8D9tTBdARB4FAWBsGwdBcF16Oy7QbXoFUtXsEAThA2-Qf2NMFrT+7lk2NNbggAyriQRRoWME26KgAFo0FwCUUGjjPNZQQBmEAz2voG75TZWgO2HWC0A3RfSuq5FQBcEAzwBZEE00BBZ15uaspbn1AMpf258x64DFnXWAL9l4r3djYZqCD4ZHTfKdLqL40TnVfig50RwqCkyLDg+BK9nCgEfqoEhKDnCujuhUW6D1ea2CJkGJg1pQBOm8m+KoTVcEfWCqwFQGgdD6HkPwhGgjlDUiUOI0hVcRL0VnOmLGUECy-SoJdZGdpNGIMUKRAGroJGgCYFImo2h6iNGaHIlBpihrKDWJsHYsjjGPRwkoucN4lwrjXBuDRWiyA2h0f9cmiCsGcVocYuxQj3ifDqD8Fx8ivaKKwsomgBFIKTDzOooMf1QDaNRiEgEYTDFRLMWwJEuwbEoIkCk4CjEHIsTYs9HJLkAlBMKXokpESjFJIkGmRglhzCPlcRIE6NBJhEwIVMuoNAJnPSUIADBBYA4FTpbA2eAkCANgCrQ+XdBaADkQZW0Ax6YEgKApA4dI7KVTnbIG1UoorRoEoOhr8MgMLkoQEUgAkEFASgEevdoBuwdLXTuezoB11wEgDOss0xkEmL0ogiMKCgB9L4faFM4jIJeMsaRgQ2BKGobzfBShZgMG3mSilQVCVxGcES8Q2Kxm4vMZYpoNL5H4IACwACZLoii+L0Ww9w1xUHMFIZMjwfQaiOIuWgtL6Ws2dm8D43xfgKv2KEvg1gFV0qxa-BEDjKnsq9iSgAjAATgAOwAAZjUSF1YQWmFDQrIv9HQWynDkWgCDFQbo+S6Cot8HwgMXqqBPP2sTMKKVgaPJin43J1QhVb0DC5QlXSfV+toXdL1KZbBDJRcSMNMUXz1Oeq8zI+VCo8hfOYSYAgHS5vzeW5wQA).